# Covariance of functional data object

Tags: covariance, functional-data-analysis

This is a follow-up question on my earlier question [Functional Regression in R: Functional Response Regressed on Scalar Covariate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/622378/functional-regression-in-r-functional-response-regressed-on-scalar-covariate).

I have a functional response $Y(t)$ (i.e., a stochastic process) which I regress on a set of scalar explanatory variables $X_1$ ($=1$, i.e., $X_1$ is a constant term), $X_2$, and $X_3$. The equation I am considering is thus $$Y(t) = \alpha(t) + \beta(t)X_2 + \varepsilon(t).$$

I am using the R package `fda`. I know how to run the regression:

```r
set.seed(313) # seed

t = 100 # time points
n = 50 # sample size

# generate some mock data
Y = sweep(matrix(rnorm(n * t, 0, 1), ncol = 50), 1, sin(1:100)) 
X2 = sample(c(0, 1), size = n, replace = TRUE)

# generate a basis for Y
Yfd = fda::smooth.basis(1:t, Y, fda::create.bspline.basis(c(1, 100), 2, 1))$fd

# run the regression
ffit = fda::fRegress(Yfd ~ X2)
```

That is, $Y(t)$ is generated by $\sin(t) + \nu(t)$, where $\nu(t)$ is a Gaussian White Noise process. The process is observed at grid points $\{1,2,\dots, 100\}$. $X_2$ is sampled from a Laplace distribution over $\{0,1\}$, and $X_3$ is sampled from a standard Normal distribution. The interface of `fda::fRegress` automatically implements a constant, so there is no need to define $X_1$.

I now know how to compute the predictions (see other questions). The next step is to include confidence intervals on the prediction. The `fda::fRegress` computes standard errors of each coefficient (after providing an argument `y2cMap`and `SigmaE). However in order to estimate the standard error of $$\hat Y(t) = \hat\alpha(t) + \hat\beta(t) X_2,$$ I need the estimated covariance of $\hat\alpha(t)$ with $\hat\beta(t)$.

I went through some of the codes of the `fda` package. However, it is only shown how to obtain the standard error for each coefficient function estimate, i.e., there is no code or explanation that shows how to get the desired covariance.